# AlarmMgr triggered sometime correct and sometimes wrong, Why?

Tags: android, alarmmanager, logcat

I set the alarmMgr like this:

```
alarmMgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
                1000 * 60 * 5L, alarmIntent)
```

and BroadcastReceiver output

```
public class BroadcastReciever extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    System.out.println("Execute time:" + Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
}...}
```

I got the correct log yesterday, then It's go wrong. It looked like trigger the alarm many times in the same time and I dont know why.I guess may be the android studio logcatch has some unknown mechanism.

> 2022-04-14 10:44:40.447 8663-8663/com.example.ss I/System.out: ...
> 2022-04-14 10:46:40.441 8663-8663/com.example.ss I/System.out: ...
> 2022-04-14 10:48:40.440 8663-8663/com.example.ss I/System.out: ...
> 2022-04-14 10:50:40.444 8663-8663/com.example.ss I/System.out: ...
> 2022-04-14 10:52:40.446 8663-8663/com.example.ss I/System.out: ...

I catch the log whole night, a part of the Log shows below.
the system log shows here ,

> 2022-04-15 07:33:39.945 13580-13580/com.example.ss I/System.out: Execute time:Fri Apr 15 07:33:39 GMT+09:00 2022
> 2022-04-15 07:33:39.951 13580-13580/com.example.ss I/System.out: Execute time:Fri Apr 15 07:33:39 GMT+09:00 2022
> 2022-04-15 07:33:39.954 13580-13580/com.example.ss I/System.out: Execute time:Fri Apr 15 07:33:39 GMT+09:00 2022
> 2022-04-15 07:33:39.960 13580-13580/com.example.ss I/System.out: Execute time:Fri Apr 15 07:33:39 GMT+09:00 2022
> 2022-04-15 07:33:39.963 13580-13580/com.example.ss I/System.out: Execute time:Fri Apr 15 07:33:39 GMT+09:00 2022
> 2022-04-15 07:33:39.966 13580-13580/com.example.ss I/System.out: Execute time:Fri Apr 15 07:33:39 GMT+09:00 2022
> 2022-04-15 07:33:39.969 13580-13580/com.example.ss I/System.out: Execute time:Fri Apr 15 07:33:39 GMT+09:00 2022
> 2022-04-15 07:35:40.066 13580-13580/com.example.ss I/System.out: Execute time:Fri Apr 15 07:35:40 GMT+09:00 2022
> 2022-04-15 08:40:40.096 13580-13580/com.example.ss I/System.out: Execute time:Fri Apr 15 08:40:40 GMT+09:00 2022
> 2022-04-15 08:40:40.103 13580-13580/com.example.ss I/System.out: Execute time:Fri Apr 15 08:40:40 GMT+09:00 2022
> 2022-04-15 08:40:40.106 13580-13580/com.example.ss I/System.out: Execute time:Fri Apr 15 08:40:40 GMT+09:00 2022

About the methods(inexact/actual time),official page said system would trigger together of some alarm in order to save battery, Alarm stats shows that, there is no so cloesd Alarm at all.I have got the correct output sometimes. I also tested method at interval 15mins, the output still went wrong.I  don't think the reason is inexact methods.

> Alarm Stats:
> 1000:android +6s300ms running, 353 wakeups:
> +3s273ms 0 wakes 40 alarms, last -4m9s148ms:
> *alarm*:com.android.server.action.NETWORK_STATS_POLL
> +2s837ms 0 wakes 226 alarms, last -4m9s148ms:
> *alarm*:TIME_TICK
> +699ms 347 wakes 347 alarms, last -1h41m9s348ms:
> *walarm*:*job.delay*
> +102ms 0 wakes 1 alarms, last -4m9s148ms:
> *alarm*:GraphicsStatsService
> +60ms 2 wakes 2 alarms, last -2h14m49s133ms:
> *walarm*:ScheduleConditionProvider.EVALUATE
> +31ms 0 wakes 1 alarms, last -8h39m9s148ms:
> *alarm*:android.intent.action.DATE_CHANGED
> +9ms 1 wakes 1 alarms, last -13h27m11s167ms:
> *walarm*:JS idleness
> +8ms 1 wakes 1 alarms, last -19h41m4s292ms:
> *walarm*:RETRY
> +6ms 2 wakes 2 alarms, last -17h41m9s348ms:
> *walarm*:*job.deadline*
> u0a40:com.android.providers.calendar +364ms running, 4 wakeups:
> +364ms 4 wakes 4 alarms, last -1h39m9s148ms:
> *walarm*:com.android.providers.calendar.intent.CalendarProvider2
> u0a89:com.android.systemui +470ms running, 27 wakeups:
> +470ms 27 wakes 27 alarms, last -14h38m7s109ms:
> *walarm*:com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindowManager.DELAYED_KEYGUARD
> u0a113:com.example.ss +4s532ms running, 0 wakeups:
> +4s532ms 0 wakes 185 alarms, last -4m9s148ms:
> *alarm*:com.example.ss/.BroadcastReciever`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- As of API 19, all repeating alarms are inexact. If your application needs precise delivery times then it must use one-time exact alarms, rescheduling each time as described above. Legacy applications whose targetSdkVersion is earlier than API 19 will continue to have all of their alarms, including repeating alarms, treated as exact.
- So if you would like to achieve exact repeating alarm use AlarmManager.setExact() and rescheduling
- Refer [google](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager#setExact(int,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent))